# HP QTP 10 Issue while logging onto the demo Mercury Website

Tags: automated-testing, qtp, ie9, windows

I am trying to log-in on the `http://newtours.demoaut.com/` demo website created by HP Mercury to do some hands on their proprietary product QTP 10. I opened this site successfully on `IE9` (Win7 X64 PC). But once I tried to sign-in to the same (to find flights) using default username/password (both - `Tutorial`) it crashed IE and I got an error - [Error snapshot](http://www2.picturepush.com/photo/a/10968380/img/10968380.png)

Comment: I have tried registering, using different browsers but it did not help. Appreciate your support.

Comment: Have you tried asking HP support ?

Comment: @PhilKirkham No I have not. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that QTP 10 supports IE9, it doesn't appear in the [PAM](http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM744522/binary/QTP10_ProdAvailMatrx.pdf).

As far as I know support for IE9 was added in [QTP11](http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM1210389/binary/QTP11.00_ProductAvailableMatrix.pdf) via some patches.